# Turf JS does not create Object properly

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I am using the [helper function](https://turfjs.org/docs/#point) `turf.point()`

```
const feature = turfHelpers.point(coords, properties, { id: properties.id });
```

`properties` looks like this

```
properties = {
  id: 1,
  thisWorks: 'no problem'
  foo: {
    thisDoesntWork: 'this is a problem'
    }
  }
```

When I create `feature` with `turfHelpers.point()`, it messes with the object. The nested object is not an `object` anymore, but gets stringyfied...

So, `features.properties` is

```
{
  id: 1,
  thisWorks: 'no problem'
  foo: "{
    thisDoesntWork: 'this is a problem'
  }"
}
```

Now, I cannot access. `feature.properties.foo.thisDoesntWork` anymore, because its a string...
Why is `turf.js` doing that?

Comment: Use JSON.parse()?

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes I could do that every time I want to access some nested properties. But why not create the object properly in the first place?

Comment: I put your (modified) code in a runnable form below. You can use it (copy) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put the question in the runnable form.

```js
const turfHelpers = turf.helpers;
const coords = [100, 14];
const properties = {
  id: 1,
  thisWorks: 'no problem',
  foo: {
    thisDoesntWork: 'this is a problem'
  }
};

var feature1 = turfHelpers.point(coords, properties, {
  id: properties.id
});

// Print out on console
console.log(feature1.properties); //look OK

console.log(feature1.properties.foo); //also OK

console.log(feature1.properties.foo.thisDoesntWork); //also OK
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.min.js"></script>
```

Then, hopefully, it is helpful for discussion that leads to a solution.